# How to render in a user defined sort order?

Tags: sql, database-design

We have a requirement to retreive books in a user defined order 
(e.g. Assuming there are 3 books - BookA, BookB, BookC), its possible that an end user would like to see this rendered as (BookB, BookA, BookC) or (BookC, BookA, BookB).

1. We are thinking of adding a integer column (e.g. sortColumn) to capture this order. Is this a good option, if the list of items is going to be huge?
2. If we go with the above approach, what is the best way to re-calculate the sort order post ordering as it might involve updating multiple records every time a book is either moved up or down.
3. Assuming there are 1000 books, how do you decide on the 'sortColumn' value for a new book which is being added.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Hibernate or JPA it's as simple as having a List on your domain object and store the ordering of the list in a column (Hibernate/JPA will automanage it for you)
Then you can interact with List to do reordering.

User->has list of UserBooks, a UserBook has an User, a Book and an Ordering

if you use hbm.xml's :

```
    <list name="books" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="iUserBookId"/>
      <index column="iOrdering"/>
      <one-to-many class="foo.bar.UserBook"/>
    </list>
```

Comment: Yes we intend to use Hibernate/JPA and assuming we store @OneToMany List<Book> in the domain object, where exactly do you want us to store the order? Can you elaborate

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to work for me. It's still not clear on how the order stickiness will be maintained in the database based on your logic.

Comment: It's stored in the iOrdering-column. Hibernate persists the index of each UserBook